# INVALID_SESSION_ID Error Salesforce Enterprise API

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, session, salesforce

Currently I am developing an integration between local services and Salesforce using ASP.net and the Salesforce Enterprise API.

However I'm encountering a problem:

> ```
> "INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session. Session not found, missing session key: xxxxxx
> This is expected, it can happen if the session has expired and swept away, or if the user logs out, or if its just someone trying to
> ```
>
> hack in."

This error appears when I try to call the create function.
When I call the query function everything works smoothly.

The session time is set to 8 hours
in "session settings" the "Lock sessions to the IP address from which they originated" is unchecked.

Any idea where the problem comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is kind of misleading here. The session id in this case won't expire on timeout, I guess it's the endpoint url that needs to be set. (Not sure). Instead of trying to understand what's causing the issue, I solved it by catching the FaultException(code below) and invoking the login again. It worked like a charm.

```
catch (FaultException ex)
{
  if (ex.Code.Name == "INVALID_SESSION_ID")
   {                    
       Login();  
       //call your method again.                  
   };
}
```